# onclick event: select item to be clicked by id

Tags: javascript

I have a button with `name="testo_da_inviare"` and I can trigger it's click event with:

```
document.forms['form_da_ricordare'].elements['testo_da_inviare'].onclick
```

Now I want to replace the `button` element with an `a` element that doesn't support the `name` attribute. So I gave the a element the `id="testo_da_inviare"`

How do I have to edit my js to trigger the onclick? Javascript is not my cup of tea and I am still learning how to use plain javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to select it:

```
document.getElementById('testo_da_inviare').onclick
```

Comment: thanks! that was what I was looking for. Didn't put the `document` at the beginning and it didn't work!

Comment: Can I combine the tag name e.g. button and the id selector in vanilla js? In jfquery it would be button#id.onclick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire an event of an element, the right way is to use dispatch method or createEventObject, not to call the element handler name

```
var eventName = "click";
var element = document.getElementById("testo_da_inviare");

if (document.createEventObject) {
   // Dispatch for IE
   var evt = document.createEventObject();
   element.fireEvent("on" + eventName, evt);
}
else {
   // Dispatch for firefox + others
   var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

   // Event type, bubbling, cancelable
   evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
   element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**- You can let the onclick event trigger on the link/button itself like this:

```
<a href="#" target="_self" onclick="thefunct()">description</a>
<button onclick="thefunct()">description</button>

function thefunct() {
    alert("button clicked");
}
```

**2**- Or on the script like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").onclick = function thefunct(){ alert('button clicked'); };
```

**3**- Or using an eventlistener like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", thefunct);

function thefunct() {
    alert('button clicked');
}
```

**4**- Or using jQuery like this:

```
$("#id").click(function(){
alert('button clicked');   
});
```

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>`